# CQRS: Is it good to return result in ICommandExecutor.Execute() method?

Tags: oop, cqrs

I have some thoughts on the design of the commanding part in CQRS. I want to hear your opinions on my thoughts. Thanks in advance! :)

In CQRS, there're Commands and CommandExecutors. Sometimes we want command executors to return some result after execution complete. One possible solution is (C#):

```
public interface ICommandExecutor<TCommand>
{
    void Execute(TCommand cmd);
}

public interface ICommandExecutor<TCommand, TResult>
{
    TResult Execute(TCommand cmd);
}
```

Good so far. We use two command executor interfaces. Now let's see the client code:

```
var cmd = new MyCommand();
commandBus.Execute(cmd);  // execute no result
commandBus.Execute<MyResult>(cmd); // execute result
```

Yes, we can let exeuctor returns result now. But the programmer might be confusing when writing the above code: Can this command be executed result or not?? To get the answer, the programmer need to look into the framework source code to see if there's a MyCommandExecutor or a MyCommandExecutor. This is bad! Very confusing!

So, in my opinion, we should **DELETE** `ICommandExecutor<TCommand, TResult>`. 
That is, **I think command executors should always return void. The design of `ICommandExecutor<TCommand, TResult>` is bad!**

If we need to see what is changed after command execution. We should make a new query to the database after calling commandBus.Execute(cmd).

What do you think about that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not add a second interface. I'm not sure if having return values is appropriate for commands in CQRS, but I sometimes do this with my commands (but I'm not following CQRS). But rather than having a second interface, add an output property to the command.

```
public class CreateCustomerCommand
{
    // customer properties here

    // output property
    public Guid CustomerId { get; internal set; }
}
```

But keep in mind that commands with output properties will never be able to run asynchronously.

If you really want to have a executor interface with a return value (which is something I won't advice), look at [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92). The article is about implementing queries in a SOLID way, but it deals with the problem of defining an type-safe interface which allows you to return data.

BTW, with the previous example, the command can be easily made asynchronous by making the `CustomerId` property an input property. You let the client supply a new random Guid. This way the client already has the ID available and doesn't have to wait for the results to become available.

Comment: The "output property" is a pretty good solution. Thanks! BTW: I'm also a freelance ;)

Answer (score 8):

In CQRS the command side should not return anything since it breaks the anatomy of the pattern. Your own thoughts about this are correct.

However, Greg Young often mention an Ack/Nack result of a command operation (or used to anyway). Most messaging frameworks support such responses. The drawback of expecting a result is that you cannot be fully asynchronous. I have never felt a need for Ack/Nack since one of the fundamentals of CQRS is that the command should always succeed so there's no point returning Ack/Nack.

Ask yourself what you need to return. What operation need to return information that you don't already have on the sending/commanding side? Take the time to figure that out before letting your commands become queries.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking if you are using command patter it should not return anything but it should be always `void`. You should use another command (query) to get any data

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx#_self1

Comment: You should use a [query](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) to get the data.